# How does this quantum circuit work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

I am getting a bit confused about how to trace through a quantum circuit.

So, for example, if you have the circuit below:

[image: Hadamard, sigmax, hadamard]

I know that the first gate would split an arbitrary state alpha|0> + beta|1> into an equal superposition of states. (Which I think can be represented by the vector 1/sqrt(2) * [alpha + beta, alpha - beta])

But then, I am starting to get confused about how to apply the sigma_x (0 1; 1 0) gate to the first qubit. (Or is it the second?)

Comment: you need to understand tensor products to understand the answer.

Comment: Hi Emily. Welcome to PhysicsStackExchange. It would be better if you write the mathematical parts of your post using MathJax. FMI, see this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation